# Counting the number of a specific character in a word?

Tags: vb6, character, counting

I am programming in vb6 and I am in need of counting the number of times a specific character occurs in a string. I know how to do this in vb.net but the method is not the same for vb6. This is what I tried,

```
 Dim sletter As String
    Dim icount As Integer

    sletter = InputBox("Enter a letter to count.")
    m_sStringtosearch = TxtString.Text
    For Each element In m_sStringtosearch
        If element = sletter Then
            icount += 1
        End If
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(sletter & " was found " & icount & " times.")
```

I used a variation of that, where there was no input box (I already have a character in mind) and no `messagebox` at the end (I'm going to use the `icount` result in an if statement).

Comment: Q: What problem(s) are you encountering?  What specifically is your question?

Comment: Well, you don't say what didn't work. My VB6 is rusty, and I don't have it installed here (or anywhere, for that matter). But I don't recall it having a += operator. I think icount is initialized to zero, but I'm not sure.

Comment: im not sure how to use the `for each` statement in vb6 because it gives me an error saying "element" is not declared. the `for each` statement doesnt work like in vb.net, so my question is either how to use a `for each` statement in vb6 or how to count a specific character another way

Comment: There is no efficient way to iterate over characters of a string in VB6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My VB6 is rusty. And this is untested. However, this should be close. VB 6 doesn't have For Each or += (I believe). I also initialized icount to 0, out of paranoia, although I believe that is something that VB6 does for you.

```
Dim sletter As String
Dim icount As Integer
Dim i as Integer
Dim element as String

sletter = InputBox("Enter a letter to count.")

m_sStringtosearch = TxtString.Text
icount = 0

For i = 1 to Len(m_sStringtosearch)
    element = Mid$(m_sStringtosearch, 1, 1)
    If element = sletter Then
        icount = icount + 1
    End If
Next

MessageBox.Show(sletter & " was found " & icount & " times.")
```

Comment: yep this works perfectly, i modified it to not need an input box however because i already had a character that will be constant. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this alternative solution

```
icount = (Len(m_sStringtosearch) - Len(Replace(m_sStringtosearch, sletter, vbNullstring))) \ Len(sletter)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Long
Dim iCount As Long

For i = 1 To Len(m_sStringtosearch)
    If LCase(Mid(m_sStringtosearch, i, 1)) = TxtString.Text Then iCount = iCount + 1
Next
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers, the system flags them as Low Quality Posts and asks for admin validation